# Handle web service error in PHP if web service link is not working

Tags: php, web-services

I am using web services in PHP written by other developer. I want to handle error and stop the execution of next code if in case web service link is not working. I am using it first time.

```
       $client = new SoapClient(url,array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
            'exceptions'=>false, 
            'trace'=>1, 'login'=>"user",'password'=>"password",'connection_timeout'=>90,
            'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_DISK ));
```

Comment: Your can check the internet status of the website, for example 404 and 200, by using php function. Search on the web by yourself which function you should use

Comment: This can be done in multiple ways. What the best implementation for you would look like totally depends on your code, which we know nothing about. Show us how you're consuming the API and we might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Updated in question

Comment: you can set timeout and get status if fail

Comment: connection_timeout is there in code.